# Undefined reference to operator new

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cpputest

I'm trying to build a simple unit test executable, using cpputest. I've built the cpputest framework into a static library, and am now trying to link that into an executable.  However, I'm tied into a fairly complicated Makefile setup, because of the related code.

This is my command line:

```
/usr/bin/qcc -V4.2.4,gcc_ntoarmle_acpp-ne -lang-c++ -O2 -g -g -o Application/UnitTests/Tests/symbols/UnitTestExe -Wl,--start-group Application/UnitTests/Tests/../.objs/main.o Application/UnitTests/lib/libcpputest.a -Wl,--end-group -lm
```

I'm getting many errors like the following:

```
 Application/UnitTests/lib/libcpputest.a(CommandLineTestRunner.o): In function `CommandLineTestRunner::parseArguments(TestPlugin*)':
   Application/UnitTests/cpputest/src/CppUTest/.objs/../CommandLineTestRunner.cpp:114: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int, char const*, int)'
```

I can't figure out what's causing this.  Don't I get operator new for free with C++?

Comment: It’s really hard to help based on this information. Try to *reduce* the conditions necessary to reproduce the problem. The above command line is far too complex, even if we assume that the code is straightforward and doesn’t do things such as redefining `operator new`.

Comment: Is the first error reported an operator new error? If not, what is the first error reported?

Comment: Yes, the only errors reported are operator new errors. That one shown is the first one.

Comment: Cases where I see undefined reference error, generally meant improper linking and proper paths not provided where libraries are installed.

Comment: Edited to remove unnecessary elements from command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's very little information in your question to work from, but it looks like some code uses some form of *placement new*, and while that special `operator new` is ***declared*** (the compiler finds it and compiles the code using it), the linker can't find its ***definition***.

*(Since this old answer of mine seems to still get attention: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719) for an extensive discussion on declaration vs. definition.)*

Comment: I'm not sure what other info to add. The code is really simple; it doesn't redefine 'new', so I can't figure why the linker can't find it from the standard library.

Comment: @mbyrne215: You could add the simplest code that reproduces this. The error message clearly mentions an `operator new(unsigned int, char const*, int)` (called from `CommandLineTestRunner::parseArguments(TestPlugin*)`), which is clearly not the standard version of that operator.

Comment: You're right; I got so hung up looking for why the standard libs weren't working, I didn't look through the 3rd party library closely. It was secretly redefining new. I removed that part and all is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 74):

You probably need to link with the C++ support runtime library. This happens automatically when you invoke g++. On Linux, this is achieved by adding the `-lstdc++` flag to the linker. You have to figure out how to do the same on your platform.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe you're calling `gcc`, the C compiler instead of `g++`, which is the C++ compiler.

Comment: **Exactly** this one-liner answer pin-pointed my fault, in which I run today.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rebuild your code from scratch, including the library. I got this error because I inadvertently copied object files compiled on another machine (with the rest of the source) to my machine. Most likely this disturbs the linking step since there are now two types of object files, native (for modified source files) and non-native (all others). I am guessing here, but the operator 'new' means slightly different things on different architectures and that's why you are getting this error.

p.s. I know this is way too late for a useful answer but I'm still posting this for the record.

Comment: in my case there were some .o files, from my predecessor, left after a make clean everything worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For QNX 6.5.0 I have specified flag `-lang-c++` for `qcc` (`gcc`) to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Like the original post, in my case this error happened while trying to link a software using CppUTest framework.

In my case, the source of the problem seems to be related to the fact I disabled the MEMORY_LEAK_DETECTION compile option of CppUTest. I enabled it again, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes adding **-lstdc++** is not enough. You should add it to the right place. For example I had list like this, not working:

```
target_link_libraries(cfr2 pthread m stdc++ "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compressor/libcompressor.a" )
```

But this one works fine:

```
target_link_libraries(cfr2 pthread m "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compressor/libcompressor.a" stdc++)
```

It'd be great if someone explained it in the comment section.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/409402/983556